# On the occurence and existence of mass conversions to Judaism after antiquity

Tags: conversion-to-judaism

I've been reading up on conversions to Judaism/the Jewish people and most conversions have been (and are) of an individual nature.
But there seem to have been a few mass conversions along the way.
I tried to find out what the religious view might be on them but I couldn't find anything. Most likely because I can't look for it in Hebrew.

So I want to know if there is a general view on it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulan_(Khazar)

Comment: @pcoz Related to that one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Aba#Origins_and_early_life

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!